# Adding folder name as a prefix to file name in R

Tags: r, file-manipulation

I would like to add the folder name in front of all file names being in this folder.

My folder name is **TempAir**, all file names within this folder are
"201401.tif" "201402.tif" "201403.tif" "201404.tif" "201405.tif"

```
files.old <- list.files(path = "TempAir")
```

Output:

```
[1] "201401.tif" "201402.tif" "201403.tif" "201404.tif" "201405.tif"
```

I would like to add **TempAir** as a prefix to all files like;

"TempAir_201401.tif" "TempAir_201402.tif" "TempAir_201403.tif" "TempAir_201404.tif" "TempAir_201405.tif"

And I try to write the code, following the suggestion of @Rui Barradas like this

```
files.new <- paste("TempAir", files.old, sep = "_")
files.new
```

Output:

```
[1] "TempAir_201401.tif" "TempAir_201402.tif" "TempAir_201403.tif" "TempAir_201404.tif" "TempAir_201405.tif"
```

And then I run the code to rename the files below

```
file.rename(files.old, files.new)
```

But, the result showed **FALSE** output like this

Output:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

What should I edit these code? Please advise

Thank you,

Kanokporn

Comment: `paste("TempAir", files.old, sep = "_")`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, your code works for adding folder name as a prefix. But I still cannot rename the new file names by using file.rename(). Could you advise me further?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to add a path to a vector. The default is the working directory.

```
add_prefix <- function(x, path = basename(normalizePath(".")), sep = "_"){
  paste(path, x, sep = sep)
}

add_prefix(files.old)
```

### Data

```
files.old <- scan(what = character(), 
                  text = '"201401.tif" "201402.tif" "201403.tif" "201404.tif" "201405.tif"')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have run your code already, and it works for adding folder name as a prefix. But I still cannot rename the new file names by using file.rename(). Could you advise me further?

Comment: @KanokpornPROMNIKORN Why can't you rename the file? Is there an error? Please describe what went wrong.